# MapReduce trouble with counting

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got a problem, I have data in mongodb which looks like this:

```
{"miejscowosci_str":"OneCity", "wojewodztwo":"FirstRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "...", ...}
{"miejscowosci_str":"TwoCity", "wojewodztwo":"FirstRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "...", ...}
{"miejscowosci_str":"ThreeCity", "wojewodztwo":"SecondRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "...", ...}
{"miejscowosci_str":"FourCity", "wojewodztwo":"SecondRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "...", ...}
```

and so on
What I want is to list all regions (wojewodztwo) and to count average number of zip codes per region, I know how to count all zip codes in region:

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.wojewodztwo,1);
};
var reduce = function(key, val) {
    var count = 0;
    for(i in val) {
        count += val[i];
    }
    return count;
};
db.kodypocztowe.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    { out : "result" }
);
```

But I don't know how to count number of cities (miejscowosci_str) so I could divide number of ZIP-Codes in region through number of cities in the same region.
One city can have multiple number of zip-codes.

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making a couple of assumptions here :

1. cities can have multiple zip codes
2. zip codes are unique
3. you are not trying to get the answer to [M101P](http://education.10gen.cc/) week 5 questions !

Rather than just counting the cities in one go, why not build up a list of city/zip objects in the map phase and then reduce this to a list of zips and **unique cities** in the map phase. Then you can use the finalize phase to calculate the averages.

**Note : if the data set is large you might want to consider using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) instead, this is shown after the map/reduce example**

```
db.kodypocztowe.drop();
db.result.drop();

db.kodypocztowe.insert([
    {"miejscowosci_str":"OneCity", "wojewodztwo":"FirstRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "1"},
    {"miejscowosci_str":"TwoCity", "wojewodztwo":"FirstRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "2"},
    {"miejscowosci_str":"ThreeCity", "wojewodztwo":"SecondRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "3"},
    {"miejscowosci_str":"FourCity", "wojewodztwo":"SecondRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "4"},
    {"miejscowosci_str":"FourCity", "wojewodztwo":"SecondRegionName", "ZIP-Code" : "5"},
]);

// map the data to { region : [{citiy : name , zip : code }] } 
// Note : a city can be in multiple zips but zips are assumed to be unique
var map = function() {
    emit(this.wojewodztwo, {city:this.miejscowosci_str, zip:this['ZIP-Code']});
};

// 
// convert the data to :
//
//    {region : {cities: [], zips : []}}
//
// note : always add zips
// note : only add cities if they are not already there
//
var reduce = function(key, val) {
    var res = {zips:[], cities:[]}
    for(i in val) {
        var city = val[i].city;
        res.zips.push(val[i].zip);
        if(res.cities.indexOf(city) == -1) {
            res.cities.push(city);
        }
    }
    return res;
};

// 
// finalize the data to get the average number of zips / region
var finalize = function(key, res) {
    res.average  = res.zips.length / res.cities.length;
    delete res.cities;
    delete res.zips;
    return res;
}

print("==============");
print(" map/reduce")
print("==============");

db.kodypocztowe.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    { out : "result" , finalize:finalize}
);
db.result.find().pretty()


print("==============");
print(" aggregation")
print("==============");

db.kodypocztowe.aggregate( [
    // get the number of zips / [region,city]
    { "$group" :
      {
          _id : {"region" : "$wojewodztwo", city : "$miejscowosci_str"},
          zips:{$sum:1}
      }
    },
    // get the number of cities per region and sum the number of zips
    { "$group" :
      {
          _id : "$_id.region" ,
          cities:{$sum:1},
          zips:{$sum:"$zips"},
      }
    },
    // project the data into the same format that map/reduce generated
    { "$project" :
      {
          "value.average":{$divide: ["$zips","$cities"]}
      }
    }
]);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you it indeed works, but I am having some trouble. My collection contains about 21k items and in result in most regions I get in zipCodes few nulls and in cities also few nulls, two regions have partial zipCodes and cities but rest contains only few nulls. It looks like there is some execution time limit, do you know how to get around it? I want to do this in mapreduce as this is my task for studies. Sorry for basic questions, I am new to mongodb. Thanks

Comment: hmm, I tried running the code over a data set containing 29,000 entries and even with a 5 sec sleep in the map method it still didn't timeout. I imagine its much more likely that there is an exception somewhere, are there any messages in the log ?  In terms of nulls, you can add a [query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce) to the **out** param to filter out the fileds that don't **$exists $and are $ne null**. The operators are [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/)

Comment: I had to change code a little bit, here is my answer: http://pastebin.com/pmPDjHWU, with cities and zips passed not within [ & ] I had nulls, now it is fine